# What are the health effects of having a fluctuating caloric intake?

Tags: diet

*This question is inspired by the paleo-diet. Not about the effectiveness of the pale-diet.*

When reading about the paleo-diet the conversation revolves around what pre-agricultural revolution people ate (or what they didn't eat). But I have never come across anything about the amount or distribution of what people ate. I imagine that hunter-gatherers had a much more varied caloric intake than people do in modern time. It is easy to imagine periods with low intake, interspersed with periods of surplus and heavy eating (successful hunt, ripening of fruit or vegetable, migration to new lush area).

I am wondering how variations, potentially large swings, in the amount you eat affects your health.

References to further reading are appreciated.

Comment: I’m closing this question because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic here unless they're directly related to medical treatments.